# Datafy/change part while retaining complete model

Tags: clojure

Newbie clojurian here. Is there a way to change the datafied part of a bigger bean and have the change reflected in the bean itself? In this case kakfa events that enters a service as a big javabean.

Not really a kafka specific problem though.

Say i have a java bean with both getters and setters, so mutable. In our case, a very big bean. So I want to just datafy the parts of the bean that one particular algorithm (or one service in our case) is interested in, mutate that part and have the original big bean retain that mutation.

Or! Even better would be if i could datafy part of an *immutable* bean and create a new bean where the datafied parts are changed, to avoid mutability.

Is there a nice way to do this in clojure? Is it possible?

This in a microservices context where each service is a kafka streaming service -

1. Big fat event in
2. Datafy and manipulate (mutate or create copy) part of that event
3. Updated big fat event out

The events/beans are generated from AVRO so we have the option of including setters of not, eg mutability.

Update - found this https://github.com/clojure/java.data. Maybe this is the proper way to go(?), going for "auto datafication" of entire event. Seems a bit expensive, converting to/from data for that big of an event so would prefer the streamlined solution if possible

Answer (score 0):

Clojure is immutable by default. When you `datafy` an object, you get back data for the whole object, and the original object is unchanged.

It sounds like you want to perform some computation on the object (or the datafied version of it), then *update parts of the original object* and emit it?

So, yes, you can choose to only mutate parts of the original object if you wish, depending on its API, but it is up to you to write the code that mutates the original object.

If you can be a bit more concrete about what exactly you want to do, we can probably provide more specific advice?

Comment: Thank you. Yes i want to change the datafied part of a bigger bean. Question updated, don't know if it is any clearer now, hope so.

Comment: Both datafy and java.data will convert the entire object to data. java.data will let you go from pure data to Java object but, as you note, it could be expensive.

Comment: I updated my answer to reflect your question edits but the TL;DR is that you'll either need to convert the entire object to data, transform (part of) it, and convert the data back to a new object -- or you'll need to write setter code yourself to mutate just parts of the original object.

Comment: Thank you Sean. I guess our model will have to be shoe horned to/from clojure friendly data. Or i need to solve it myself with some kind of intelligent map thingy, maybe. I will investigate and hopefully find a nice way to solve this